# Setting up password/confirm password without [Compare]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, password-confirmation

I am using Asp.net MVC to create a password and confirm password field. I am currently using the remote attribute to check if password and confirm password are the same, however remote will only call a function if the box it is applied to is changed.

I've looked through previous posts going back to last year and found the most common suggestion to be the compare attribute, however it is now deprecated.

I assume there is a pre-built solution for this problem.

This is from the model

```
    [Remote(UserController.ActionNameConstants.PasswordMatch,
       UserController.NameConst, AdditionalFields = "ConfirmPassword", 
       ErrorMessage = "The passwords do not match")]
    [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage="Minimum password length is 8")]
    [DisplayName("Password"), RequiredIf("Id == 0", 
      ErrorMessage="Password is required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Confirm Password"), RequiredIf("Id == 0", 
        ErrorMessage = "Confirm password is required")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

This is in the controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual JsonResult PasswordMatch(string password,string confirmPassword)
     {
       return this.Json(password == 
       confirmPassword,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }
```

Comment: So after further research, it appears that there is still a version of Compare that is not deprecated, so any of the solutions using Compare are still valid using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation.Compare().

Answer (score 1):

Compare is not depricate you can still use [Compare("Property name to compare with")]... it's in "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" namespace.